# Rotate the scrollbar button's image

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar, transform

I would like to rotate the scrollbar button's image, here's my scrollbar codes: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Hepxc/
I want to rotate the second image for the y axis 180 degrees, and for the x axis 90 degrees.
I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
transform: rotate(10deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
```

Comment: Why in the world would you apply a `-moz` style to a load of `-webkit` rules?

Comment: What do you mean? if there's something that I should fix in my FIDDLE code please tell me, if you are talking about the code in the gray area it's not written by me and I don't use it

Comment: The images in your fiddle aren't working, and I was referring to your use of `-moz-transform` in your startpost - not much point in adding Mozilla Firefox specific styling rules to a Webkit-only feature.

Comment: it should work very good I don't why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

1. Do `transform: rotateX(XXdeg) rotateY(XXdeg);` to rotate by specific axis.
2. If you want a 3D effect, give the parent object a "perspective" of e.g. 600px: `perspective:600px;`. Without a perspective on the parent element, you won't see a 3D effect (in case you want this behaviour).

Comment: It didn't work :( I tried to add your both codes and it doesn't work.
here's the new code adding your codes to it:
`::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ygGobeC.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transform: rotateX(XXdeg) rotateY(XXdeg);
    perspective:600px;    
}`<br>
Please try to get it work with my codes in the fiddle website, I'm giving 20 reputation for the answer.. :)

Comment: I'm not a friend of browser-specific CSS and set on wide compatibility instead (thus not too aware of webkit-specific rules), however, you may find this customizeable scroller plugin interestring: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ For more examples, see http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html